# Can website with high traffice bring down other websites

Tags: web-applications, webserver

I have a rookie question. Suppose we have a website (www.abc.com) on server 1 and a second website www.xyz.com on server 2 and the second website is referencing some files(css or javascript) on server 1. Can high traffic on server 1 slow down server 2?

Comment: Well, it certainly can slow down the apparent performance of server 2 if they share a net pipe. (I don't think there's really any good answer to this question other than to understand exactly what's going on and reason out the effects.)

Comment: If website 2 is google.com, and website 1 is hosted on a godaddy shared hosting account, then yes. (Point is, it depends on the situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You can read about something related, the [slashdot effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect) at wikipedia, that explains real cases in an informative way.

Comment: Thanks, the links is helpful. I never knew about it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It can slow down other websites which are hosted on same server or hosted on other server.

It can happen due to following few issues:

1. Hardware : if you used RAM with low capacity
2. IIS pooling
3. IIS caching

If you do not properly manage IIS it hampers server performance.

If you used IIS7 onward then IIS can internally manage 2nd and 3rd issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I've seen it happen. In the case I witnessed, server 2 was serving something more complex than just static files, it was a widget that displayed on the server 1's site. That widget in turn, did a DB query on server 2's DB, and the rest is history.

It's certainly less troublesome to server 2, if it's only serving static files, but again the short answer is yes, that the traffic can become a strain on server 2 no matter what is being served, if the traffic is high enough.